# Asana API order by

Tags: asana

Does the Asana API support ordering results? I would like to get the the most recent 100 projects via '/projects' (https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/projects#query), ordering by created_at descending. It looks like it returns the results by created_at in ascending order.

I see that I can use pagination to limit the number of records returned (https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/pagination), but I don't see any way to sort or order the results.

Answer (score 1):

Asana platform developer here: The API doesn't support any sorting/ordering at all. :-/ Obviously having ordering together with pagination allows some much more efficient usage patterns, so we'd like to, but we don't have it yet and it's not (currently) on the road map. We are looking to overhaul how items (tasks, projects, etc.) are queried in general - we think better filtering and ordering options are best developed in tandem, rather than bolted on top of what we currently have.